# rsync complaining about `missing trailing-"` in a Bash script

Tags: bash, ssh, rsync

Trying to rsync files from one server to the other in a screen session.  Instead of writing the long command every single time, I decided to put in a Bash script.  However, when I run it, I get a `Missing trailing-" in remote-shell command.` error.

Wondering what is going wrong in the script.

```
root@127.0.0.1:~# /raid/data/module/bin/rbk.sh Movies /raid/data/Movies rsync_target/

/raid/data/module/bin/screen -S Movies 

/opt/bin/rsync --rsh="ssh -p 10022 -c des"\
--rsync-path="/opt/bin/rsync" --inplace --progress -a -vv \
/raid/data/Movies sys@192.168.1.15:/raid/data/rsync_target/

Missing trailing-" in remote-shell command.
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(361) [sender=3.0.5]
```

The script echoes what it will do first and then executed the command.  Below is a dump of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
SCREEN="/raid/data/module/bin/screen"
SCREENOPT="-S"
SCREEN_TITLE=$1

RSYNC="/opt/bin/rsync"
RSYNCOPT="--rsh=\"ssh -p 10022 -c des\" --rsync-path=\"/opt/bin/rsync\" --inplace --progress -a -vv"

SOURCE=$2

REMOTE_USER="sys@"
REMOTE_HOST="192.168.1.15"
REMOTE_BASE=":/raid/data/"
REMOTE_TARGET=$3

echo ${SCREEN} ${SCREENOPT} ${SCREEN_TITLE}

echo ${RSYNC} ${RSYNCOPT} ${SOURCE} ${REMOTE_USER}${REMOTE_HOST}${REMOTE_BASE}${REMOTE_TARGET}
${RSYNC} ${RSYNCOPT} ${SOURCE} ${REMOTE_USER}${REMOTE_HOST}${REMOTE_BASE}${REMOTE_TARGET}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Short answer: see [BashFAQ #050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Long answer: the problem you’re having is that embedding quotes in variables doesn’t work the way you think it does.  Specifically, quotes are parsed before variables are replaced, so if a variable’s value includes quotes it’s too late for them to work right.  When you set `RSYNCOPT="--rsh=\"ssh -p 10022 -c des\" ..."` and then use `${RSYNCOPT}` in a command line, the quotes in the variable don’t get parsed, they’re just treated as normal characters.  Thus, rather than the rsync command receiving a single parameter `--rsh=ssh -p 10022 -c des`, it receives 5: `--rsh="ssh`, `-p`, `10022`, `-c`, and `des"`.  Since the --rsh command contains a single (unmatched) quote, you get an error.

To see what’s going on better, either use `set -x` to make the shell print each command before executing it (so you can see what’s really happening), or replace the `echo ${whatever}` (which is highly misleading) with `printf "%q " ${whatever}; echo`.

There are several ways to solve this.  One is to avoid trying to store `RSYNCOPT` (and probably other things as well) in variables in the first place.  Another is to store `RSYNCOPT` as an array (which can keep track of word boundaries without any of this confusion) rather than a simple string.

To print the command before executing it, either use `set -x` before the rsync command and set +x after to turn it off, or use something like the `printf` command I listed above (note that it prints a stray space after the command, but this generally doesn’t matter).

Here’s the array+printf approach:

```
...
RSYNCOPT=(--rsh="ssh -p 10022 -c des" --rsync-path=\"/opt/bin/rsync\" --inplace --progress -a -vv)
...
printf "%q " ${SCREEN} ${SCREENOPT} ${SCREEN_TITLE}
echo

printf "%q " ${RSYNC} "${RSYNCOPT[@]}" ${SOURCE} ${REMOTE_USER}${REMOTE_HOST}${REMOTE_BASE}${REMOTE_TARGET}
echo
${RSYNC} "${RSYNCOPT[@]}" ${SOURCE} ${REMOTE_USER}${REMOTE_HOST}${REMOTE_BASE}${REMOTE_TARGET}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, anyway a quick look to the link you provided convinced me that a function is more readable (or at least it becomes so when properly formatted):

`run_rsync() {
/opt/bin/rsync "--rsh=\"ssh -p 10022 -c des\" --rsync-path=\"/opt/bin/rsync\" --inplace --progress -a -vv" $1 $2
}

run_rsync ${SOURCE} ${REMOTE_USER}${REMOTE_HOST}${REMOTE_BASE}${REMOTE_TARGET}`

(I know, this is quite old, but still one of the first links when searching for "Missing trailing-" in remote-shell command")

Answer (score 8):

The maze of escaped and unescaped quotation marks in your `$RSYNCOPT` confuses the heck out of me; I'm not surprised that it confuses rsync, and/or ssh, and/or the local or remote shell.

There may be a way to get this to work by adding or removing backslashes, but I suggest the following workaround instead:

Replace:

```
RSYNCOPT="--rsh=\"ssh -p 10022 -c des\" --rsync-path=\"/opt/bin/rsync\" --inplace --progress -a -vv"
```

by:

```
export RSYNC_RSH="ssh -p 10022 -c des"
RSYNCOPT="--rsync-path=\"/opt/bin/rsync\" --inplace --progress -a -vv"
```

I tried a slightly simplified version of your script on my system and got the same error message you did; this workaround corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [ssh configuration file](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) is also a valid option. Here's what you can put/add to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Port 10022
Cipher des
```

You can also [filter these parameters by remote host](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/) by prepending these lines with `Host xyz.domain.whatever` and indenting them:

```
Host 192.168.1.15
    Port 10022
    Cipher des
```